# Scale image for tablets and phones

Tags: html, css

I noticed that on some of my webpages, when I browse them on ie. tablet or an Android phone, the images seem too big while the rest of the website is scaled down properly. Is there a CSS property or something that would make my images scale down properly when viewed on tablets/phones?

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm talking about when using background-image CSS property

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Yes you could use media queries

check the following links to get started.
Hope this helps

```
http://mediaqueri.es/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
```

sample example

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
  img
  {
   background-image:url('yourimage.jpg)";
   height:50px;
   width:50px;

  }

}

@media screen and (max-width:750px)
{
  img
  {
   background-image:url('yourimage.jpg)";
   height:250px;
   width:250px;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good form, but if you add the following css to images on the page they will scale

```
img.content {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

(However they will also still download the entire giant image to the phone so be careful not to use anything huge, and if you can add your image to a site that will detect if it's a phone or a desktop, so you can send the giant image to the desktop, and a smaller, more phone-bandwidth friendly image to the phone)